# Determine the dimensional form of Young’s modulus given that E=Stress/Strain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

Using dimensional analysis, determine the dimensional form of Young’s modulus given that:

Young's Modulus E= stress/strain

Am I correct in thinking that this could be written as
[M][L]^-1[T]^-2?

I'm just a little confused on how I got there :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Strain is dimensionless (it is one length divided by another) so the dimensions of Young's modulus are the same as the dimensions of stress, which is a force divided by an area.

Comment: It is better to consider strain as [L]/{L] instead of [1] .